# How to retrace the execution of completed XCM Transact calls?

Tags: xcm, hrmp, debugging, transact

How can someone retrace what actually happened during the execution of the `Transact` message?

Recently the Zeitgeist parachain (2,092) sent an [XCM](https://polkadot.subscan.io/xcm_message/polkadot-72ac4993e1c3e0151b8f7bf21ac37e44c811108c) to Polkadot that includes a `Transact` message that calls `hrmp.hrmpCancelOpenRequest`. This XCM apparently was completed, as seen [here](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/16427469-1?event=16427469-42) and [here](https://polkadot.subscan.io/xcm_message/polkadot-72ac4993e1c3e0151b8f7bf21ac37e44c811108c). This XCM was previously successfully tested on Rococo using the adjusted parachain ids. However, on Polkadot the desired result (channel canceled) was not achieved and neither any events nor state traces indicate what internally happened.

Comment: were you able to debug on the polkadot side? Did it error out? @sea212?

Comment: Never figured out what actually happened. As far as I can tell there is no indication of an error. It seems as it executed successfully to me, but there are no state changes.